# power automate xpath problem with 0 results on namespaces input

Tags: xpath, power-automate

I am working on implementing a small test case for power automate for which in part I am getting data from a website in the xml format. Am getting 0 results though. Worked through a lot of documentation and guessing its something with the namespaces. Cant find any problem with the xPath command though,basically just copied from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#xpath Example 9

XML File (Content deducted for privacy):

```
<?xml version=""?>
<message:GenericData
    xmlns:message=""
    xmlns:common=""
    xmlns:xsi=""
    xmlns:generic="">
    <message:Header>
        <message:ID>830b24b2-4a0a-4514-98f5-1cf6c8ac30f5</message:ID>
        <message:Test>false</message:Test>
        <message:Prepared>2023-01-19T08:39:56.121+01:00</message:Prepared>
        <message:Sender id=""/>
        <message:Structure structureID="">
            <common:Structure>
                <URN>urn:sdmx:org.sdmx.infomodel.datastructure.DataStructure=ECB:ECB_EST1(1.0)</URN>
            </common:Structure>
        </message:Structure>
    </message:Header>
    <message:DataSet action="">
        <generic:Series>
            <generic:SeriesKey>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:SeriesKey>
            <generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:Attributes>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
        </generic:Series>
        <generic:Series>
            <generic:SeriesKey>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:SeriesKey>
            <generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:Attributes>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
        </generic:Series>
        <generic:Series>
            <generic:SeriesKey>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:SeriesKey>
            <generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:Attributes>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
        </generic:Series>
        <generic:Series>
            <generic:SeriesKey>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:SeriesKey>
            <generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:Attributes>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
        </generic:Series>
        <generic:Series>
            <generic:SeriesKey>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:SeriesKey>
            <generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:Attributes>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
        </generic:Series>
        <generic:Series>
            <generic:SeriesKey>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:SeriesKey>
            <generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:Attributes>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
        </generic:Series>
        <generic:Series>
            <generic:SeriesKey>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:SeriesKey>
            <generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:Attributes>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
        </generic:Series>
        <generic:Series>
            <generic:SeriesKey>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:SeriesKey>
            <generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:Attributes>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
        </generic:Series>
        <generic:Series>
            <generic:SeriesKey>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:SeriesKey>
            <generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
                <generic:Value id=""/>
            </generic:Attributes>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value=""/>
                <generic:ObsValue value=""/>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                    <generic:Value id=""/>
                </generic:Attributes>
            </generic:Obs>
        </generic:Series>
    </message:DataSet>
</message:GenericData>
```

xPath Command

```
/*[local-name()="GenericData" and namespace-uri()="message"]/*[local-name()="DataSet" and namespace-uri()="message"]/*[local-name()="Series" and namespace-uri()="generic"]/*[local-name()="Obs" and namespace-uri()="generic"]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What this command intended to do?

Comment: And why did you removed namespace and PI aka process instruction ? `<?xml version=""?>
<message:GenericData
    xmlns:message=""
    xmlns:common=""`

Comment: **This is not valid XML**

Comment: I just regexed everything out that was in quotationmarks, so I know that it is not valid anymore, in the original there is a version etc.

Comment: @Prophet this is intended to give a list of all Obs groups for a count command to see, how many there are

Comment: We can't tell if the namespace-uri() in your XPath is correct if you remove it from the source XML.

Comment: @MichaelKay I think I misunderstood where the namespace part is. Though it was the generic: and message: part that was the namspace, not the definition, that is given in the beginning of the document.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your namespace URIs being all empty, it doesn't make sense to try using `namespace-uri()`.

Using `name()` might be a better option:

```bash
/*[name()="message:GenericData"]/*[name()="message:DataSet"]/*[name()="generic:Series"]/*[name()="generic:Obs"]
```

Comment: From what I understood from the documentation of xml the "message" part in "message:GenericData" is the namespace, isnt that correct?

Comment: @eskay https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-name

Comment: Tryed it though just now with this methode and it worked. 

I think I tryed it earlyer today with /message:GenericData/message:DataSet/generic:Series/generic:Obs and it just threw out an error of a malfomed xpath command and according to this site : is a namespace seperator

Thanks for the help though, took me a whole 8 hour workday to get it working
https://www.brainkart.com/article/XPath--Operators,-Special-Characters-and-Syntax_8668/

Comment: In 8 hours you could have read a book on XPath and made yourself familiar with all the concepts. Are you sure you have the right learning strategy?

Comment: @MichaelKay

Thing is I wasnt even sure, that the problem was Xpath because Xpath tester were hit or miss (the original xpath that was used came from one and didnt work), it was the first time using Xpath for me and it could also have been very plausible, that Power Automate just acted really strange. But I totally agree, that I should have used a more systematic approach towards the problem. Well, to late now, just marked for the future